# How to add handler to ListBoxItem in code?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, .net-4.5

I'm trying to solve my problem using addHandler method, but I have no idea how to set its parameters correctly.
My approach is:

```
lbi.AddHandler(OnMouseLeftButtonUp, GoToEditDraft, true);
public static void GoToEditDraft()
    {

    }
```

I want to have the method GoToEditDraft triggered when user clicks on ListBoxItem (lbi). I understand that my mistakes in data types, that I didn't set. How to set it correctly?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*I want to have the method GoToEditDraft triggered when user clicks on ListBoxItem (lbi)*". So how about this way :

```
lbi.MouseLeftButtonUp += GoToEditDraft;
private void GoToEditDraft(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs)
{
    //TODO: put some logic here
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That works. I am new to Windows Phone and .net api scares me sometimes.

Comment: haha.. feel free to ask. In most case, .NET exposes API in easiest way possible. Maybe prior knowledge of other programming language with different style (python maybe?) that make thinking in .NET way seems not straightforward

Comment: and what should I do if I want to send an additional parameter to GoToEditDraft method, when MouseLeftButton is clicked on lbi?

Comment: `sender` contains the object that trigger the event (in this case the ListBoxItem being clicked). `var clickedLbi = (ListBoxItem)sender;` will bring you the `lbi`. I hope that enough without adding additional parameter (because it is not possible to add other parameter to the method).